# How to get cells to stack inlined HTML media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to get tables to go inlined when in a mobile device. I created a css class saying `display:inline` for two `TR`'s but it does not seem to work.  This was placed in a media query as well

I want two cells to be right beside each other in mobile view - is this possible?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="130" style="line-height: 16px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9.5pt; font-weight: normal;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr class="kinline">
                <td>
                  <img alt="" width="105" height="126" src="https://custom.cvent.com/66C0FC65436D454680AE32F058BA1240/pix/eff1bb6b639f4555bcd180351e45a52f.jpg" />
                  <p style="margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9.5pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><strong>Name Surname</strong>
                  </p>
                  <p style="margin: 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">Job title
                    <br />Member firm
                    <br />Department
                  </p>

                  <img alt="" width="105" height="126" src="https://custom.cvent.com/66C0FC65436D454680AE32F058BA1240/pix/eff1bb6b639f4555bcd180351e45a52f.jpg" />
                  <p style="margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9.5pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><strong>Name Surname</strong>
                  </p>
                  <p style="margin: 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">Job title
                    <br />Member firm
                    <br />Department
                  </p>

                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="kinline">
                <td>
                  <img alt="" width="105" height="126" src="https://custom.cvent.com/66C0FC65436D454680AE32F058BA1240/pix/eff1bb6b639f4555bcd180351e45a52f.jpg" />
                  <p style="margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9.5pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><strong>Name Surname</strong>
                  </p>
                  <p style="margin: 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">Job title
                    <br />Member firm
                    <br />Department
                  </p>

                  <img alt="" width="105" height="126" src="https://custom.cvent.com/66C0FC65436D454680AE32F058BA1240/pix/eff1bb6b639f4555bcd180351e45a52f.jpg" />
                  <p style="margin: 5px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9.5pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;"><strong>Name Surname</strong>
                  </p>
                  <p style="margin: 0px 0px 4px; padding: 0px; color: #000000; line-height: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal;">Job title
                    <br />Member firm
                    <br />Department
                  </p>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `tr` isn't going to respond to `inline` because of it's display type. Tables are not going to be the most flexible option for responsive layouts.

Comment: *"I want two cells to be right beside each other in mobile view - is this possible?"* When you say "cells" I'm assuming `<td>` or `<th>`. If so, that's the very nature of a cell is to be inline (next to each other) within a `<tr>`.

Comment: If you want to give a tr `display:inline` then you should go the whole hog and also change the display values of the table and the tds. Otherwise you're just fighting the system.